# How does as.POSIXct "tryFormats" work with multiple input types?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct

I have been confused about how `as.POSIXct` tries different formats, and why does it work in some cases and not in others.

In the following reprex, there are dates formated `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` and others `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`. As expected, if using the `format` option, only the dates fitting that format will be successfully returned. I would have expected that using `tryFormats` with both formats would successfully convert all dates. Why is it not the case? Why does `lubridate` returns what is expected?

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
options(lubridate.verbose = TRUE)

datetimes = c("3/1/2015 23:44",
              "3/2/2015 1:01",
              "3/29/2015 0:56",
              "3/29/2015 1:00",
              "3/29/2015 00:56:01")

as.POSIXct(datetimes, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
#> [1] "2015-03-01 23:44:00 GMT" "2015-03-02 01:01:00 GMT"
#> [3] "2015-03-29 00:56:00 GMT" NA                       
#> [5] "2015-03-29 00:56:00 GMT"
as.POSIXct(datetimes, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#> [1] NA                        NA                       
#> [3] NA                        NA                       
#> [5] "2015-03-29 00:56:01 GMT"

as.POSIXct(datetimes, 
           tryFormat = c("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
           optional = T)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

as.POSIXct(datetimes, 
           tryFormat = c("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
           optional = T)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

mdy_hms(datetimes, truncated = 1)
#>  1 parsed with %Om/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S
#>  0 parsed with %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S
#>  4 parsed with %Om/%d/%Y %H:%M
#> [1] "2015-03-01 23:44:00 UTC" "2015-03-02 01:01:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2015-03-29 00:56:00 UTC" "2015-03-29 01:00:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2015-03-29 00:56:01 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>